# email and password authentication in springboot like firebase

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, authorization

I am currently working on a small project.
I use flutter for the frontend and springboot for the backend.
I want the springboot application to run locally on a raspberry pi.

Now I am wondering, if it is possible to implement a firebase (email/password) like authentication/authorization in springboot (without using firebase or any other cloud-based solutin) where you don't have to login every time you open the app.

Or you could compare it to facebook, instagram, snapchat, ... in all of these apps you stay logged in the whole time.

What possible ways are there to implement this in springboot?

I mean I could store the login credentials on the phone but I guess that wouldn't be secure or the correct way, right?

Comment: How do you login?

Comment: email and password but the login process should only happen once like in the mobile version of fb, instagram, snapchat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are approaching, there are several ways you can authenticate your end user in the mobile application.

- Using email password
- Using phone number verification
- Using third party authentication provider ( facebook, gmail etc)

Without knowing your target end users, its hard to determine appropriate authentication mechanism.

By far as you are developing a flutter application and targeting mobile users, i assume your end users has some sim card installed in their mobile device and using the phone number and otp based solution seems frictionless for your end user.

You can use firebase admin sdk, prompt the user to type in their phone number and send otp to that phone number, then ask the end user for the correct otp. Send back the otp to firebase, firebase will give you a idToken (a token in firebase realm). Pass that idToken to the server ( spring boot rest service) and verify it from firebase. firebase will reply with user details ( basically the phone number)

Whole process involves setting up a firebase project, installing admin sdk and some tweaking in both mobile application and spring boot end.

For more info start here https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: yeah that could work, but is there also an option without using firebase at all? and i would like to use email and password for registration and login

Comment: Please state your question precisely.